# Retrieve Documents - filtering

Tags: doctrine-odm, doctrine-phpcr

It's possible to simply filter retrieved Documents by using:

```
$dm->findBy(array('field' => 'value'))
```

But I need something a bit more suited to Content Repository specifics.
So, is there a way to retrieve Documents (e.g. equivalent to "SELECT ... WHERE ..."), filtered by:

- an array element (e.g. by first element of a field having multiple values: something like arrayFields[0])
- path node, e.g. I want to get only children (but not using getChildren() method of a Document) under given path, e.g. /cms/routes/categories - this should return only Documents having '/cms/routes/categories' at the beginning of their path (or Id field)

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is (yet?) not available API for the exact solution as mentioned. PHPCR (not ODM) have the features which in a certain way may make these tasks done, though.

The above tasks can be acheived by:

1. Filtering simply by a multiple-valued field. E.g. if you have "authors" field as an array, the PHPCR seems to correctly sort and filter document by first author available; furtherore in PHPCR (again, not ODM) API there's an equivalent to in_array() PHP function. It's treated as any other (not multivalued) field - http://doctrine-phpcr-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder-reference.html#literal
2. With filtering by a path, there are three possibilities (the one I mentioned as needed is the third one):

   - "same": by the exact Id path, e.g. /cms/routes/article/title-of-article will return only this single particular result - http://doctrine-phpcr-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder-reference.html#same
   - "child": by the direct children of a path, e.g. /cms/routes/article will return all direct children at the /cms/routes/article level (this one /cms/routes/article/title-of-article will be returned among others) - http://doctrine-phpcr-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder-reference.html#child
   - "descendant" by the children of any nested levels below, e.g. /cms/routes will return also /cms/routes/article/title-of-article (unlike in the second case) - http://doctrine-phpcr-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder-reference.html#descendant

For more, here are docs available: http://doctrine-phpcr-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html and http://doctrine-phpcr-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder-reference.html